# Handle japanese characters on C++ using Marmalade SDK

Tags: c++, casting, localization, wchar-t, marmalade

I'm just starting to create a localization system using marmalade SDK that will needs to handle a Japanese characters.
I'm currently using `VS2010` to compile the project, and in my project I'm just created the following lines in order to handle a japanese phrase example:

```
const wchar_t* loc_splash_loading = L"  荷重...";
```

The problem is, since I need to pass the text through the Marmalade SDK functions to draw the text on screen, I need to use:

```
void IwGxFontPrepareText(CIwGxFontPreparedData& data, const uint16 * text, int32 len = -1);
```

or

```
void IwGxFontPrepareText(CIwGxFontPreparedData& data, const IwChar * text, int32 len = -1);
```

I assume that I need to use the function with `const uint16 * text`, but I don't know how to cast `const wchar_t*` to `uint16 * text`.

Someone can helps me with this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is... it depends !

`wchar_t` may be 8, 16 or 32 bit-wide, `C90` and `C99` do not use the same size, `ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Unicode standard 4.0` leaves the size up to the implementation.

You have to look into your code to see how `wchar_t` type is defined. Most of the time (and on windows) it is actually an `uint16_t` : in this case you can safely and directly cast it.
Otherwise, you can for example use `wcstombs` function to convert wide chars to multi-bytes, and then convert the result from `UTF-8` to `UTF-16` (cf `iconv`).

Some links on the subject:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)
- [GNU libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/The-wchar_005ft-mess.html#The-wchar_005ft-mess)
- [linux.com archive](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/51836)